# Angular 5: My response don't overwrite default property

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-httpclient, angular4-httpclient

I try to bind data in my html view, but my response don't overwrite default property value. From the API I get good response.

**feedback.statistics.model.ts**

```
export class FeedbackStatistics {
  overall: number = 0;
  technicalSkills: number = 0;
  communication: number = 0;
  commercial: number = 0;
  leadership: number = 0;
}
```

**reviews.component.ts**

```
export class ReviewsComponent implements OnInit {

  message = '';

  feedback: FeedbackStatistics = new FeedbackStatistics();

  constructor(
    private profileService: ProfileService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.profileService.getUserFeedbackStatistics().subscribe(
        response => {
            this.feedback = response;
        },
        error => {
            this.message = error.error_description;
        }
    );
  }
}
```

**reviews.component.html**

```
<!-- User Skills -->
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap text-center g-brd-around g-brd-gray-light-v4 g-pa-20 g-mb-40">
  <div class="g-mr-40 g-mb-20 g-mb-0--xl" style="margin-left: 17px;">
    <app-counter [from]=0 [to]=feedback.overall [of]=10 [animationTime]="700" [circleColor]="'#d3b6c6'" [fontSize]="80"></app-counter>
    <h4 class="h6 g-font-weight-300 g-mt-5 mb-0">Overall</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="g-mr-40 g-mb-20 g-mb-0--xl">
    <app-counter [from]=0 [to]=feedback.technicalSkills [of]=10 [animationTime]="700" [circleColor]="'#bee3f7'" [fontSize]="80"></app-counter>
    <h4 class="h6 g-font-weight-300 g-mt-5 mb-0">Technical Skills</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="g-mr-40 g-mb-20 g-mb-0--xl">
    <app-counter [from]=0 [to]=feedback.communication [of]=10 [animationTime]="700" [circleColor]="'#ffc2bb'" [fontSize]="80"></app-counter>
    <h4 class="h6 g-font-weight-300 g-mt-5 mb-0">Communication</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="g-mr-40 g-mb-20 g-mb-0--xl">
    <app-counter [from]=0 [to]=feedback.commercial [of]=10 [animationTime]="700" [circleColor]="'#c9ff97'" [fontSize]="80"></app-counter>
    <h4 class="h6 g-font-weight-300 g-mt-5 mb-0">Commercial Acumen</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="g-mb-20 g-mb-0--lg">
    <app-counter [from]=0 [to]=feedback.leadership [of]=10 [animationTime]="700" [circleColor]="'#eeeeee'" [fontSize]="80"></app-counter>
    <h4 class="h6 g-font-weight-300 g-mt-5 mb-0">Leadership</h4>
  </div>
</div> <!-- End User Skills -->
```

**profile.service.ts**

```
    getUserFeedbackStatistics(): Observable<FeedbackStatistics> {
    if (!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authorizationData'))) {
        return Observable.empty<FeedbackStatistics>();
    }

    return this.http.get<FeedbackStatistics>('api/reviews/feedbackStatistics?username=' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authorizationData')).userName)
    .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
}
```

For example, if I leave it as stated in the code, I get it result 0 for all property, but if I declare like this: "feedback: FeedbackStatistics;" I get response value but than i have error that feedback can't be undefine.

Any proposal would be welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: try using `changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();`

Comment: What do you get if you log the `response` before you assign it to the `this.feedback`?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Thanks for your suggestion. I've already tried and did not work. :(

@ThomazCapra I get good response: 
`Object { overall: 1, technicalSkills: 1, communication: 1, commercial: 1, leadership: 1 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think adding a `*ngIf="feedback"` to the outermost div should fix the feedback can't be undefined problem like this: 
**reviews.component.ts**

```
export class ReviewsComponent implements OnInit {

  message = '';

  feedback: FeedbackStatistics;

  constructor(
    private profileService: ProfileService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.profileService.getUserFeedbackStatistics().subscribe(
        response => {
            this.feedback = response;
        },
        error => {
            this.message = error.error_description;
        }
    );
  }
}
```

**reviews.component.html**

```
<!-- User Skills -->
<div *ngIf="feedback" class="d-flex flex-wrap text-center g-brd-around g-brd-gray-light-v4 g-pa-20 g-mb-40">
  <div class="g-mr-40 g-mb-20 g-mb-0--xl" style="margin-left: 17px;">
    <app-counter [from]=0 [to]=feedback.overall [of]=10 [animationTime]="700" [circleColor]="'#d3b6c6'" [fontSize]="80"></app-counter>
    <h4 class="h6 g-font-weight-300 g-mt-5 mb-0">Overall</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="g-mr-40 g-mb-20 g-mb-0--xl">
    <app-counter [from]=0 [to]=feedback.technicalSkills [of]=10 [animationTime]="700" [circleColor]="'#bee3f7'" [fontSize]="80"></app-counter>
    <h4 class="h6 g-font-weight-300 g-mt-5 mb-0">Technical Skills</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="g-mr-40 g-mb-20 g-mb-0--xl">
    <app-counter [from]=0 [to]=feedback.communication [of]=10 [animationTime]="700" [circleColor]="'#ffc2bb'" [fontSize]="80"></app-counter>
    <h4 class="h6 g-font-weight-300 g-mt-5 mb-0">Communication</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="g-mr-40 g-mb-20 g-mb-0--xl">
    <app-counter [from]=0 [to]=feedback.commercial [of]=10 [animationTime]="700" [circleColor]="'#c9ff97'" [fontSize]="80"></app-counter>
    <h4 class="h6 g-font-weight-300 g-mt-5 mb-0">Commercial Acumen</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="g-mb-20 g-mb-0--lg">
    <app-counter [from]=0 [to]=feedback.leadership [of]=10 [animationTime]="700" [circleColor]="'#eeeeee'" [fontSize]="80"></app-counter>
    <h4 class="h6 g-font-weight-300 g-mt-5 mb-0">Leadership</h4>
  </div>
</div> <!-- End User Skills -->
```

And also, I don't think you should use a class for FeedbackStatistics since you don't add any methods. You could just use an inteface like this:

**feedback.statistics.model.ts**

```
export interface FeedbackStatistics {
  overall: number;
  technicalSkills: number;
  communication: number;
  commercial: number;
  leadership: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One , The constructor is not explicitly defined which is okay, I guess

Two, you need to map the response to json, if it not done in the angular service before subscribing it.

Third ,

```
 feedback: FeedbackStatistics = new FeedbackStatistics();

  constructor(private profileService: ProfileService) {
feedback= new FeedbackStatistics();
 }
```

this needs to be in the constructor

Comment: This is in profile.service.ts:

`getUserFeedbackStatistics(): Observable<FeedbackStatistics> {
        if (!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authorizationData'))) {
            return Observable.empty<FeedbackStatistics>();
        }

        return this.http.get<FeedbackStatistics>('api/reviews/feedbackStatistics?username=' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authorizationData')).userName)
        .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
    }`

I'm import HttpClient, HttpHeaders, and in console log i get good response but default value is not changed :(